# (^# | ^ *$) ! Is this regular expression supported?

Tags: regex, shell

I used *grep '(^#|^  *$)' file* to search lines in a text that  begins with '#' or an empty line.

But it doesn't work.

Because When I read the book 'sed & awk', it says that *grep* doesn't totally use all metacharacter in regular expressions's grammar.

So I doubt .Is the expressions '(^#|^ *$)'  just illegal in regular expressions ?Or it is because grep doesn't support this kind of grammar.

---

Doubts again.
'\' :close the special meaning of following character. sometimes it's opposite. The opposite one I know is '()' '{}'. is '|' also the opposite one? still exist some?
Thanks.

Comment: This should probably be `^(#.*| *)$` to correctly match lines beginning with `#`.

Comment: my problem is mainly "how to use |" . but still thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\|` instead of a bare `|` to make this otherwise OK expression work with grep.

From the man-page:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
>   lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?,
>   +, {, \|, (, and ).

So try this expression:

```
grep '\(^#\|^ *$\)' input
```

or:

```
grep '^\(#\| *$\)' input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe that I make such a mistake.

Comment: Surrounding the patterns with quotes can avoid this problem without escaping meta-characters.

Comment: @HuiZheng, did you try to do that?

Comment: @perreal try what? I have given my answer( `grep -E '(^#|^ *$)' input_file` ) and it worked.

Comment: grep -E '(^#|^ *$) file or grep '\(^#\|^ *$\)' file are ok. but which metacharacter (I have known () and {})  need '\' to open the special meaning while *grep without -E option*?

Comment: read the man-page quote above, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use grep "or"

```
grep -e '^#' -e '^ *$' filename
```

[**ref**](http://thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators)

Answer (score 0):

You can use egrep, which is an enhanced version of grep. Or, alternatively, add `-E` option to `grep`. Besides, to avoid conflict with special characters in shell(e.g. *, |), you'd better surround regexp with quotes.